# Can I prevent auto-update of apps with changed permissions?

Tags: permissions, application-autoupdate

I would like to auto-update any app that has no change in permissions.  Apps with changed permissions, I would like to review the changes before updating.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose do not auto update from the setting of play store 
when you open Play Store > My Apps (from NAVIGATION Drawer) if there will be any notification to update apps .. 
**when you choose UPDATE / UPDATE all then it will ask for accept permissions if there is any change in permissions**

Well it is not possible but If you want to stop Auto-update apps on android then this might be the perfect answer
 1. Open PLAY STORE
 2. Play Store Setting
 3. TAP AUTO-update apps
 4. Choose From Options

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does this prevent auto-update of apps whose permissions have changed?

Comment: when you choose do not update & open your play store after couple of days if there is notification 2 update apps in MY APPS section. when you tap UPDATE ALL
if there would be change in permission of apps
a dialogue box will ask for SKIP or Accept with the permission
suppose you have 7 apps update & there are 4 apps with Change in permission
when you TAP UPDATE ALL 
4 dialogue box will appear one by one 
if you choose SKIP then it will start updating apps those 3 app with no change in permission
if you accept all four dialogue box then it will start updating all 7 apps

Comment: I know.  I'm looking for a way to have apps with no changes in permissions to be **auto-updated** *without user action*.  I think your answer is "It is not possible".  Even with root priv and some other blocker app installed(?)

Comment: well i have done that earlier thats why i am suggesting you..